# How do I nicely display json rows using html and javascript by a grouping

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, node.js

So I have been trying to figure this out for hours, the answer is probably right in front of my face as it usually is.

Basically I have an array in the following format

```
[
     TextRow{
        unitsession_id: 19,
        unitsession_title: 'Lecture week 1',
        unitsession_description: 'Week 1 lecture',
        unitsession_type: 'Lecture',
        unitsession_weekno: 1,
        unitsession_unit_id: 5
    },
    TextRow {
        unitsession_id: 20,
        unitsession_title: 'Practical 1',
        unitsession_description: 'Week 1 practical',
        unitsession_type: 'Practical',
        unitsession_weekno: 1,
        unitsession_unit_id: 5
    },
    TextRow {
        unitsession_id: 23,
        unitsession_title: 'lecture week 2',
        unitsession_description: 'Week 2 another practical',
        unitsession_type: 'Lecture',
        unitsession_weekno: 2,
        unitsession_unit_id: 5
    }
]
```

I want to be able to display these on a HTML page by grouping of unitsession_unit_id. In this particular case it would show something like this...

**Week 1:**

Lecture week 1

Practical 1

**Week 2:**

Lecture week 2

The JavaScript (Node JS) I am currently using brings out the data as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INp33.png).

JavaScript:

```
const sessWeekTemp = document.getElementById('sess_week_temp');
const sessWeekAddNextBefore = sessWeekTemp.nextElementSibling;

let sessTemp = undefined;
let addNextBefore = undefined;

let test = undefined;
for(let i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++){
    if (sessions[i].unitsession_weekno != test) {
        test = sessions[i].unitsession_weekno;
        const sessWeekNoEl = document.importNode(sessWeekTemp.content, true);
        sessWeekNoEl.querySelector('.weekno').textContent = "Week " + sessions[i].unitsession_weekno;
        sessWeekTemp.parentElement.insertBefore(sessWeekNoEl, sessWeekAddNextBefore);
        sessTemp = document.getElementById('sess_temp');
        addNextBefore = sessTemp.nextElementSibling;
    }
   const sessEl = document.importNode(sessTemp.content, true);
   sessEl.querySelector('.sessiontitle').textContent = "Title: " + sessions[i].unitsession_title;
   sessEl.querySelector('.sessiondesc').textContent = "Description: " + sessions[i].unitsession_description;
   sessEl.querySelector('.sessiontype').textContent = "Type: " + sessions[i].unitsession_type;
   sessTemp.parentElement.insertBefore(sessEl, addNextBefore);
}
```

The HTML for this is as following:

```
<h2 id="sessions">Sessions</h2>
         <template id="sess_week_temp">
            <p class ="weekno">Week1</p>
            <template id="sess_temp">
                <article class="addsession">
                  <p class="sessiontitle">session title</p>
                  <p class="sessiondesc">session desc</p>
                  <p class="sessiontype">session type</p>
                </article>
             </template>
         </template>
```

I have not used JavaScript for very long and I am still very much experimenting so any help/pointers would be amazing, thank you.

Comment: Q can you explain more exactly "what output you want achieve" and "what output you have now"?

Answer (score 0):

please try jquery templates, for examples refer this [link: introduction-to-jquery-templates](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates)`

you might have to create a new json object with desired grouping/hierarchy based on the 'TextRow' array elements.

Comment: Thanks for the link Senthil, on first look it looks quite interesting. I do think though that my current JavaScript code could be slightly changed to produce the correct result. I am displaying the results, just they're not coming in the way I want them to.

Answer (score 0):

First, what is `TextRow` doing in the middle of the array?

**Sort the data**

> ... by grouping of unitsession_unit_id.

It looks like you really want to group by is

- `unitsession_unit_id` then by
- `unitsession_weekno` then by
- `unitsession_type`

Sort the data by that ordering...

```
let theData = [
{
    unitsession_id: 19,
    unitsession_title: 'Lecture week 1',
    unitsession_description: 'Week 1 lecture',
    unitsession_type: 'Lecture',
    unitsession_weekno: 1,
    unitsession_unit_id: 5
}, // etc.
];

theData.sort((x,y)=> {
  if(x.unitsession_unit_id > y.unitsession_unit_id) return 1;
  if(x.unitsession_unit_id < y.unitsession_unit_id) return -1;

  if(x.unitsession_weekno > y.unitsession_weekno) return 1;
  if(x.unitsession_weekno < y.unitsession_weekno) return -1;

  if(x.unitsession_type > y.unitsession_type) return 1;
  if(x.unitsession_type < y.unitsession_type) return -1;

  return 0;
});
```

Comment: @DannySanderson, you said  *"... just they're not coming in the way I want them to"*.  Do you think sorting addresses the problem?